# How to assign admin role to user in MEAN stack

Tags: mongodb, roles

I have created many users and am using mongoClient . Now i have to add admin role and allow the admin to give permission to other users to access certain menu's.

I have searched but i don't have any idea to assign roles in mongoclient .

Comment: *"Allow access to certain menu's"* has absolutely nothing to do with MongoDB. If you are asking about how to configure things in a certain framework then  you need to specifically as that question of the framework. Right now it's unlclear what you are asking.

Comment: Now only i have cleared. Actually i have to create separate field to add role. Then based on the roles i have to give access to the certain menus